# Javascript print using setTimeout

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set a delay between the time the pdf is opened and the print function is called on the pdf file. Currently nothing happens but if I move the print function outside of the setTimeout it will call the print function but this is not what I want because it is too quick and pdf has not been loaded. When I place alerts inside the setTimeout they are called fine with the specified 3 seconds.

```
var pdfWin = window.open(docPath);
setTimeout(function() {
   pdfWin.print();
},3000)
```

My question is: why is the print function not being called?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You shouldn't use timeouts for that purpose. You can't possibly predict the time it will take for a file to be downloaded because the internet speed of the users and the server's response time *will* vary. You should use an event handler that fires when the file is downloaded.

Comment: I understand this and it is not the final solution. I just want to see the output before I move on to something else

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var pdfWin = window.open(docPath);
pdfWin.onload = function() {
    pdfWin.print();
};
```

Works fine for me in chrome.

Due to [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), you can only call `.print()` on the window if it resides on the same domain as the parent window. Otherwise I could just open up your facebook on my page and submit some forms there ;p

Comment: +1 - Nice solution. Maybe it's nice to say for other users, that this only works, when `docPath` is a reference that is located on the same domain. Otherwise `onload` won't fire.

Comment: @insertusernamehere yes I added a mention of that now :)